# Python - Can you help me make a class from a piece of code I'm repeating?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

Below I am reusing a piece of code when I set the instruct1 and instruct2 variables. I tried a couple of things yesterday to make a class but was unable to do it properly. Would anyone be willing to help? Thanks in advance.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

HEIGHT = 700
WIDTH = 1100

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#08295e')
frame.place(relx=0.01, rely=0.01, relwidth=0.98, relheight=0.98)

prog_title = tk.Label(frame, text='test program')
prog_title.config(width=30, font=('Eras Medium ITC', 30), bg='#08295e', fg='white', bd=7)
prog_title.pack()

instruct1 = tk.Label(frame, text='Step1: Do step 1', anchor='nw')
instruct1.config(width=30, font=('Microsoft JhengHei Light', 15), bg='#08295e', fg='white')
instruct1.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.1)

instruct2 = tk.Label(frame, text='Step2: Do step 2', anchor='nw')
instruct2.config(width=30, font=('Microsoft JhengHei Light', 15), bg='#08295e', fg='white')
instruct2.place(relx=0.05, rely=0.2)

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('my.TButton', font=('Microsoft JhengHei Light', 12))

button = ttk.Button(root, text='Create Stuff', style='my.TButton')
button.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.3, relwidth=0.17, relheight=0.05)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: why not just a function?

Comment: Can you show what kind of class you've tried to make? It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look, which values are constant between this lines and wrap them inside a function and define the others to be parameters.

```
def make_label(my_text, my_offset):
      temp = tk.Label(frame, text=my_text, anchor='nw')
      temp.config(width=30, font=('Microsoft JhengHei Light', 15), bg='#08295e', fg='white')
      temp.place(relx=0.05, rely=my_offset)
      return temp

instruct1 = make_label('Step1: Do step 1', 0.1)       
instruct2 = make_label('Step2: Do step 2', 0.2)
```

Comment: Got it thanks. I was trying to make a class because I learned about it this weekend, but this way works fine. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please accept the answer, if it solves your problem? Otherwise, I can help you turning your code into a class as well.